# Referencing to a Maven module on IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Using intelliJ 13.1.
When trying to add a maven module to a maven Project I am unable to reference to its classes.

Things I tried:

- Re-importing and even creating a new module.
- Compiling the inner project first.
- ALT+Enter -> add project dependency -> point to the inner module.
- Adding the dependency to the pom file myself.
- Adding :" compile "  to the dependency.
- Clearing cache.

Unfortunately, nothing seem to work.

Comment: Compare the pom files and check that artifact versions are the same

Comment: have you tried to 'install' inner project first?

Comment: Does it work with plain Maven (on the terminal)?

Comment: Versions are ok. I did , I installed the inner one first.